# How to display only Transit Routes[for trains] in Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a requirement to plot polylines in between two points in a map. But for that first i have to load a map which will have only railway track routes. Is is possible to display only railway tracks on Google Maps API. If so API, Else is there any alternative API that can be used. Or else can a static mape be loaded in Google Maps . Currently I am using Google maps API.
Can static geographical maps be loaded in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Use [map-styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) to hide  particular features on a map(or in your case hide everything and draw only specific features).

style-example that only draws landscape and transit-lines:

```
[ //hide everything
  { "featureType": "all", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } ] },
  //show landscape
  { "featureType": "landscape.natural", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] },
  //show transit-lines
  { "featureType": "transit.line", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" } ] } ]
```

There is no option to select only railways, but usually `transit.lines` will only affect railways.